# I can't connect internet through Vodafone dongle

Tags: 12.04, installation, internet, usb-modem

I have connected the dongle to my laptop, it shows in network manager with my network provider name (tata docom), but can't connect to internet.

How can I fix this?

Writing in terminal  `lsusb`  command gives following output

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 19d2:0143 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
```

here ZTE wcdma is my dongle device

> Device: usb0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Type:              Mobile Broadband (GSM)
>
> Driver:            cdc_acm
>
> State:             disconnected
>
> Default:           no
>
> Capabilities:

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Do you know the brand and model of your dongle? Please edit your question to include that information. Also, look for Q&A in this site for your specific model.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output of the following commands in the terminal: `nm-tool`, `ping -c4 4.2.2.2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with installing

**V-Mobile-Broadband**

It is the Vodafone Mobile Broadband Driver with GUI

You can install it with *ppa:crass/v-mobile-broadband* [Repository](https://launchpad.net/~crass/+archive/v-mobile-broadband/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:crass/v-mobile-broadband

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install v-mobile-broadband
```

Answer (score 0):

I have put up an answer here:

[ubuntu 13.04 recognizes usb mobile broadband modem as ethernet connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367341/ubuntu-13-04-recognizes-usb-mobile-broadband-modem-as-ethernet-connection)

Just change the vendor and product id appropriately as per your requirements.