# ubuntu 13.04 recognizes usb mobile broadband modem as ethernet connection

Tags: network-manager, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

When I plug in my USB mobile broadband modem (ZTE MF-667), in the network manager instead of a mobile broadband connection, I get an Ethernet connection, called: Ethernet Network (ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM), which of course doesn't work.

Here is my `lsusb` output and the relevant parts of `dmesg` output:

```
lsusb:  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b1b9 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Asus Integrated Webcam  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM   

dmesg:  
[  195.328467] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci  
[  195.423545] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=1225  
[  195.423555] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4  
[  195.423561] usb 2-1.1: Product: ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM  
[  195.423567] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated  
[  195.423572] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: P680A1ZTED000000  
[  195.426319] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0  
[  196.425354] scsi 7:0:0:0: CD-ROM            CWID     USB SCSI CD-ROM  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2  
[  197.447919] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3  
[  197.457582] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 243x/186x xa/form2 cdda pop-up  
[  197.457594] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20  
[  197.459058] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0  
[  197.459483] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5  
[  197.759186] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci  
[  197.854543] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=1405  
[  197.854556] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=3, SerialNumber=5  
[  197.854564] usb 2-1.1: Product: ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM  
[  197.854572] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated  
[  197.854579] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: P680A1ZTED010000  
[  197.957739] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.2  
[  198.076554] cdc_ether 2-1.1:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:a0:c6:00:00:00  
[  198.076583] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether  
[  198.955985] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            CWID     USB SCSI CD-ROM  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2  
[  198.956797] scsi 8:0:0:1: Direct-Access     ZTE      MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
```

I created the appropriate mobile broadband connection manually, but I cannot enable it in network manager, since the device is not recognized as mobile broadband.

Any tips how to make it work?

Comment: First install ZTE linux modem drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! This is one of the problems I have been facing and here is a possible solution. Looking at your `lsusb` output, I find the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
```

This indicates that the Vendor ID is `0x19d2` and the Product ID is `0x1405`. I would advise you the following steps:

(1) Create a `bash` script as follows. This bash script is to be run, everytime you would like to use your mobile modem CDMA connection. Let us suppose that the name of the `bash` script is `myModem.sh. Do this by typing:

```
sudo nano ~/myModem.sh
```

Type in the following lines here:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /sbin/modprobe usbserial vendor=0x19d2 product=0x1405
```

Save your script and exit from `nano`. Type:

```
sudo chmod +x ~/myModem.sh
```

(2) Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install wvdial 
sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
```

(4) Type the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/90-zte.rules
```

and type in the following line (it is a single line and no carriage returns please):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block",SUBSYSTEM=="scsi",ATTRS{model}=="USB Storage 1405",ACTION=="add",RUN+="/sbin/modprobe usbserial vendor=0x19d2 product=0x1405"
```

Save the file and exit from `nano`.

(5) Now run your bash script from your home directory:

```
sudo ~/myModem.sh
```

(6) Now we have to configure `wvdial`.

```
sudo wvdialconf /etc/wvdial.conf
```

This will detect the modem and create a configuration file.

(7) Edit the configuration file to adjust the setting according to your country/service provider. Especially change the dialing phone number, username and password. Do this by typing

```
sudo nano /etc/wvdial.conf
```

Remove the semicolons before the phone, username and password. The semicolons tell wvdial that these lines are commented. Save your file and exit from `nano`.

(8) Now create your connection. Make sure you check the Connect Automatically option.

I hope this will set your modem working.

Comment: I tried this method, but couldn't get my modem to work. 
At the 6th step, i got the following output: 
`Scanning your serial ports for a modem.

Modem Port Scan<*1>: S0   S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6   S7 
  
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S8   S9   S10  S11  S12  S13  S14  S15 
 
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S16  S17  S18  S19  S20  S21  S22  S23
  
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S24  S25  S26  S27  S28  S29  S30  S31
  


Sorry, no modem was detected!  Is it in use by another program?
Did you configure it properly with setserial?`

How should I configure it with setserial so the port scan finds the device?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with ubuntu 13.10 detecting ZTE MF667 as ethernet connection. The solution posted here didn't work for me, as wvdial was not able to detect it as a modem - which makes perfect sense, because it is an ethernet device. After trying different solutions, I stumbled upon this:

http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1662

And finally I understood, that there is no problem with usb-modeswitch or anything!

You don't need to configure your connection in the ethernet settings at all. As I use it with an O2 sim card, I just connect to the ZTE ethernet connection, open my browser and go to "o2surf.stick" (this might be similar for your provider). I found this when I tried to run the setup.exe provided on the ZTE in Wine. There I can enter the PIN (can be disabled in the settings later) and connect to the mobile network. After that everything works fine :)

The interface provided by o2 reminds me of our wlan router config. You can see there your connection duration and the data volume used.

Sorry, if my English is somewhat awkward...

I hope, this might help some people.

Comment: On the Telstra 3G USB+WiFi version of this, the configuration settings page is at http://m.home